# Searching for NULL value on button press

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

I have a button that when you click it, it loads a list. That button sends the value of it, then it uses that value to populate the list based on that. I have some that are null and would like to be able to select that too. The problem being you can't do `Color = Null`. It just is `Color IS NULL`

```
<button value="NULL">NULL</div>
<button value="White">White</div>
```

Clicking White:

```
        $q = $_GET['q']; /--This gets White--/
        $people = $db2->prepare("select Name from Table where Color = ? ");
        $people->execute(array($q)); /--This searches White--/
        $data = $people->fetchAll(); 
        foreach ($data as $row): ?>
```

Do I have to edit my jquery function to get the null value or is there a way to make it work just like this? Thanks!

Comment: You could do a conditional, ie. `if($q == 'NULL') $where = ' IS NULL'; else $where = ' = ? ';` And you change to `"select Name from Table where Color $where "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a NULL-safe equal to operator in mysql, so you can write your query like

```
"select Name from Table where Color <=> ?"
```